# Unlock achievement in google play games silently, without showing notification

Tags: android, google-play-services, achievements

I'm using google play services, achievements in my android game (it's actually unity, but doesn't matter).

To unlock achievement I use plugin which calls [unlock(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#unlockImmediate%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String%29) method. When achievements are set as completed, google shows its own notification, like this:
[image: notification].

I need to unlock achievement silently, without showing this notification. Is there anything to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who wants an answer for this:

When you build your `GoogleApiClient` using `new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)` you are giving Game Services an activity with which it can show notifications. If you change the context you pass into the builder to be the application context, rather than an activity,  you shouldn't get any notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock the achievement in IntentService. Then it doesn't have any visual context to show the notification in.