# How to hide popping up Google Play's unlocked achievement programatically?

Tags: android, notifications, google-play-games, achievements

I have fully implemented some Achievements for my new Android App that uses the Google Play Service. But I am wondering how or whether I can disable/hide the notification that pops up when you have unlocked an Achievement **programatically**?

(Google search couldn't answer my question so far)

Comment: I assume you want to do that from your app, not for general games? I tried to clarify it by adding that to your question. Feel free to edit/rollback.

Comment: Thx Andrew for editing my post. Yes, your assumption was correct. I want to hide the achievements notification for a specific app and not for all apps.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not tried this, I think it can be achieved by setting a hidden view to use for the Play Games Service - see the [setViewForPopups](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#setViewForPopups%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.view.View%29) method for configuring which view to use.

Alternately, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376439/unlock-achievement-in-google-play-games-silently-without-showing-notification) which might also work.

Comment: I tried the code from another answer you have linked in your post, but it didn't work unfortunately. So I am gonna try out the public method setViewForPopus. But does anyone have any experience how to disable this methode?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Play Games app Google Play Games.
Near the top left, touch the Play Games icon Google Play Games.
Touch Settings.
Change your notification settings.

Note: To turn off all Play Games notifications, you can uncheck the boxes next to all notification options.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129346?hl=en&ref_topic=6027059

Comment: It appears that this workflow only works for people who have downloaded my app already. Then they can setup their notification settings etc. in their google play account. But in my case, I need to setup the achievement notifications in advance before I release my app.